# Add new line to validation error in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How to I add an error with a line break? When I try adding `\n` it gets ignored, and when I try adding `<br>`, it just displays it.

Controller:

```
errors.add(:base, "This is the first line \n this is the second line")
```

View:

```
<% if message_form.errors.any? %>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class= 'col-md-12'>
      <div id="error_explanation" >
        <h5><%= pluralize(message_form.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited error prevented save:</h5>
        <ul>
        <% message_form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use `<br>` together with [html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) helper to mark that string as safe and skip all additional escaping.

However, you should take into account that if you mark as `html_safe` a string with user-provided inputs (or external inputs in general) you may be exposed to HTML injection or XSS attacks.

In case that is what you are trying to achieve, I would like to mention that you can associate more than one error to the same attribute, as explained in the [Rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add).

Comment: It’s really one error just two lines. So if I add multiple errors, it gives multiple lines, but also adds the the number of counted errors. Thank you